# Переносимость кода и запись запросов

Tags: sql, postgresql

На уроке прочитал вот такое: 
СОВЕТ: ключевое слово `FROM`
В некоторых реализациях `SQL` ключевое слово `FROM` после инструкции `DELETE` является необязательным. Однако хорошей практикой  считается указание этого ключевого слова даже в тех случаях, когда этого не требуется. Поступая таким образом, вы обеспечите переносимость кода между разными СУБД.

1)

> Не очень понимаю переносимость кода между разными СУБД?
>   
>   То есть каждый запрос записывается, чтобы мы могли потом в файле получить все запросы которые были в данной базе данных?

> Как осуществляется переносимость? Как можно отследить это? Ну то есть в 
>   некоторых реализациях SQL ключевое слово FROM после инструкции DELETE
>   является необязательным. То есть записывается куда-то запрос или что?

Comment: sql, postgresql, mySQL и тд - СУБД (Системы управления базами данных) . Языки запросов у них отличаются. Поставив from вы несколько увеличите "переносимость кодда" - количество СУБД, в которых запрос выполнится без ошибки.

Comment: @splash58 я разбираюсь в СУБД и знаю что языки запросов у них разные. Куда это всё записывается, что мы потом перенести схему можем?

Comment: Имеется в виду "если Вам потребуется выполнить этот запрос, но на другой СУБД, не придётся его редактировать, приспосабливая под особенности новой СУБД, можно будет его выполнять как он есть". Как это будет делаться - руками, софтом,- дело десятое.

Comment: я не понимаю, видимо, вопрос. Например, у вас написан в том же php запрос к БД. Вы переходите с одной СУБД на другую. Много ли вам запросов придется переделывать - вот и вопрос переносимости

Comment: @splash58 Смотрите, я написал запросы(чтобы переносимость была без проблем) на PostgreSQL, дальше я выкачиваю файл где все запросы, где база данных и тд и гружу в MySQL эти файлы из PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MikeMclaren может быть да, а может быть нет. Зависит от того, как понимать `дальше я выкачиваю файл где все запросы, где база данных и тд и гружу в MySQL эти файлы из PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 0):

Переносимость кода подразумевает соответствие стандарту языка SQL. Он развивается, но СУБД могут иметь следовать лишь его  [базовой ***Core*** части](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Далее уже идут индивидуальные различия каждого языка (T-SQL, PL/pgSQL, PL/SQL, которые могут не совпадать в конструкциях. Общая база сейчас - это SQL-99. Там `FROM` - обязателен. Реализуемая конкретной СУБД поддержка SQL может этого не требовать, но поставив его - формально легче адаптировать скрипт для выполнения на другой СУБД.